# Problem with removing last row of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

This is my first time asking here so forgive me if something isn't appropriate, and sorry if my English isn't very good.

Well, to make it short, currently I'm developing a Java desktop app with Swing and I have a problem using table. I have rows with each row have a button to delete the row. Everything is okay (i can delete rows with no problem) until i try to delete the last row. The last row can be deleted but apparently there is an exception, something like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2710)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4712)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:125)
```

From the stack trace, it seems that "4" is my previously deleted last row index, but i have no idea how to deal with this. I already search for solution but i still can't solve it. Note that there are still other rows when i delete the last row, and after that i can't delete the others rows. The same exception also resulted when i click the delete button.

Oh. and I use removeRow() from DefaultTableModel to delete the row. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**
These are the code I use.

```
public class ViewDetail extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener {
    ...
    String column[] = { "Aaa", "Bbb", "Delete This"};

    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    Object row[][] = new Object[size][column.length];

    //fill the data from db
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    row[r][0] = ...;
    row[r][1] = ...;
    row[r][2] = "Delete";
    r++;
    }

    tableModel.setDataVector(row, column);
    table = new JTable(tableModel);

    tableColumn = table.getColumn("Aaa");
    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(75);
    tableColumn = table.getColumn("Bbb");
    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(75);
    tableColumn = table.getColumn("Delete This");
    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(75);
    tableColumn.setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
    tableColumn.setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox());
     ...
}

public class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {
    public ButtonRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}

public class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    protected JButton button;
    private String label;
    private boolean isPushed;
    private JTable table;
    public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
        button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
    label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    button.setText(label);
    isPushed = true;
    this.table = table;
    return button;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    if (isPushed) {
                  DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();                            
                  tableModel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());                
            }
            isPushed = false;
    return new String(label);
    }

    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
}

protected void fireEditingStopped() {
        super.fireEditingStopped();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code snippet that performs the deletion operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing is trying to set the new value into the row you remove!  Try moving the remove code into a Runnable and use invokeLater in the swing utility class to execute it.

Comment: Thanks a lot vickirk. It's working now. I simply wrap the removeRow in a Runnable, though i'm still not understand how Swing trying to set a new value into the row I remove.

Comment: Just had a luck in more detail, the remove code is actually in the call to getEditorValue, so you are actually removing while it is attempting to set the value in the model ,by the time it calls set value it's gone from the list.

Answer (score 1):

could you post the code where you init, add elements and delete in your JTable?

My first guess is that you are either doing the classical mistake 
"I have 4 elements in my table so to delete the last one I remove(4)" when you your table goes from 0 to 3 in indices

or you are trying to remove several object in the same loop like

```
  for(int i = 0; i<lenght; i++){
       if(i%2==0){//every even number
         tab.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

then your are modifying the size of your table, the elements are shifted but your not taking it in account when removing.

those are just guesses/pointer to what might cause the problem. please post your code if this doesn't solve it

Comment: No, i delete it one by one. And i'm pretty sure i use the right indices because i use the table.getSelectedRow(), which will return the index that start from 0, as the parameter for the table.remove() method. For the code, i will try to post it soon.

Answer (score 1):

The [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) shows how you can render a column as a button and how to add an Action that is executed when the button is clicked. The example Action just happens to show how to delete a row.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I still think my delete button implementation kinda messed up, so it's good to see another option.

Comment: @ordinarydot, Yes your implementation is messed up and the solution is a hack because of the bad design. The function of the getEditorValue() is to get the value from the editor and store the value in the model. It is not designed to do processing which is why you need the hack to solve the problem. There are other problems with the editor which you probably haven't discovered yet. Taking shortcuts is not the way to solve a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply camickr, I really appreciate it. I'm still noob at Java actually, so I don't know that it's a bad design (randomly search a working implementation in the net), but yeah, maybe because of the bad design I am struggling with the code right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to remove only 0 th row that should be iterated

private void refreshTable() {
       int rowCount= model.getRowCount();
      // System.out.println(rowCount);

```
   for(int i=0;i<rowCount;i++ ){
        model.removeRow(0);
        //System.out.println(i);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add new vaiable and check to fireEditingStopped() :

```
public class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

//create new variable 
private boolean isDeleteRow = false;
/////////////////

protected JButton button;
private String label;
private boolean isPushed;
private JTable table;
public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
super(checkBox);
button = new JButton();
button.setOpaque(true);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
        }
    });
}

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
    boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
if (isSelected) {
    button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
    button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
} else {
    button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
    button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
}
label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
button.setText(label);
isPushed = true;
this.table = table;

// set false when click to button
isDeleteRow = false; 
/////////////////
return button;
}

public Object getCellEditorValue() {
if (isPushed) {

              // set true when isPushed button
              isDeleteRow = true;   
              /////////////////

        }
        isPushed = false;
return new String(label);
}

public boolean stopCellEditing() {
isPushed = false;
return super.stopCellEditing();
}

protected void fireEditingStopped() {
    super.fireEditingStopped();

     //check if isDeleteRow, remove row
     if(isDeleteRow)
     {
          DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();                            
          tableModel.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());   
     }
     /////////////////
}
}
```