# how to clear JTable

Tags: java, swing

How can i clear the content of the JTable using Java..

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439210/deleting-datas-in-the-table-in-gui/4439297#4439297

Comment: Dupe of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879610/clear-contents-of-a-jtable

Answer (score 96):

You must remove the data from the `TableModel` used for the table.

If using the `DefaultTableModel`, just set the row count to zero. This will delete the rows and fire the `TableModelEvent` to update the GUI.

```
JTable table;
…
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);
```

If you are using other `TableModel`, please check the documentation.

Comment: Just adding this in here... I had to call `table.revalidate();` after setting the row count to zero in order to see the change immediately, otherwise I didn't see the change until I clicked the `JTable`.

Comment: @Jim-Dingo works fine without `revalidate()` for me: [simple example](http://pastebin.com/iDgLeKPk) The `DefaultTableModel` informs the view when data was changed - check the code of `setNumRows(int)`, it calls `fireTableRowsDeleted` if the row count is decreased.

Comment: perhaps @Sakiboy is using the older JDK so he need to revalidate() it everytime the model changed.

Comment: @gumuruh, yes this is an OLD answer

Answer (score 23):

Basically, it depends on the TableModel that you are using for your JTable. If you are using the `DefaultTableModel` then you can do it in two ways:

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
dm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
dm.fireTableDataChanged(); // notifies the JTable that the model has changed
```

or

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
while(dm.getRowCount() > 0)
{
    dm.removeRow(0);
}
```

See the JavaDoc of [DefaultTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) for more details

Comment: Remember to fire an table event if you change the underlying data vector - else the JTable will have no clue that it has changed...

Comment: -1, both suggestions are wrong. The first, for the reason commented above. The second will skip rows because the variable i keeps incrementing as you remove each row. If you want to create a loop then you just keep removing row 0, until there are no more rows. However, Carlos posted the simplest solution.

Comment: Camickr, you are right. I changed my answer to fix these issues. Still Carlos's solution is easier to implement.

Answer (score 7):

I had to get clean table without columns. I have done folowing:

```
jMyTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
```

Comment: quick and effective solution but it also removes the header. It should be better if there's an option to not remove the header. Someone in another post suggested to remove all the rows one by one. That would keep the header

Answer (score 4):

This is the fastest and easiest way that I have found;

```
while (tableModel.getRowCount()>0)
          {
             tableModel.removeRow(0);
          }
```

This clears the table lickety split and leaves it ready for new data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant that you want to clear all the cells in the jTable and make it just like a new blank jTable.
For an example, if your table is myTable, you can do following.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
myTable.setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we use `tMOdel.setRowCount(0);` we can get Empty table.

```
DefaultTableModel tMOdel = (DefaultTableModel) jtableName.getModel();
tMOdel.setRowCount(0);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
((DefaultTableModel)jTable3.getModel()).setNumRows(0); // delet all table row
```

Try This: