# Stop Duplicate row entries in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, code-duplication

I am searching with `textfield(suppose "99")` value and entries are displayed in JTable.

Again if I search with `99` same values will added in JTable which I don't want.

Please provide any suggestions:
Much appreciated in advance.

**-- Edit --**

```
Textfield1 - 99    Textfield2 - abc
```

**-- Search --**

`Button Pressed`

**-- JTable Loaded --**

```
Column1     Column2    Column3
5            abc        2000
10           abc        5000
15           abc        6000
```

Again if I search with same(`99,abc`) `Textfield1` and `Textfield2` values same entries should not get added.

But if searched with different values(`66,xyz`) then results("2 new rows") should be appended to the table resulting in total of 5 rows.

**Code for reference:**

```
List gettblList = retrieveCMGDtable(MYTABLE); //Retrieving table Rows
List tblList = getResultList(); //Method for getting result rows
```

**//Appending rows**

```
gettblList.add(tblList);
populateCMGDtable(MYTABLE,gettblList);//Populating table with  rows appended
```

Comment: *"Please provide any suggestions"*  Post a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577792/how-to-clear-jtable

Comment: thnx matt but I want to append rows not clear the the table and populate new results. @matt

Comment: thnx Andrew Thompson
I have provided minimal example.
@AndrewThompson

Comment: thnx @a_horse_with_no_name for editing and understanding

Comment: *"I have provided minimal example."*  An example of what?  By MCVE I mean Java code that can be compiled and run to show the problem.  Voting to close..

Comment: Code for reference is provided.
It's not perfect but I think it is sufficient.
I will try and put the rows in Hashset for removing duplicate rows@AndrewThompson