# How can I remove all row from DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to remove all row in a DefaultTableModel.
So I have build this code:

```
package com.mcsolution.table.MioTableModel;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import com.mcsolution.common.LoggerFactory.MyLog4J;


public class defaultTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3656308616639186983L;
    public  NumberFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    public static NumberFormat decimalFormatter4 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0000");
    public MyLog4J log = new MyLog4J();

    public defaultTableModel(){}
    public defaultTableModel(String[] ColName,int n){
        super(ColName, n); 
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value,int row,int column){
        super.setValueAt(value, row, column);
    }

    public void removeAllRow(){
        if (getRowCount() > 0) {
            for( int i = getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            {
                removeRow(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code, to create a JTable

```
tableModel2 = new MyTableModelArticoliDett_Vieste(colName,listaMagazzino);
sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModelArticoliDett_Vieste>(tableModel2);
tableModel2.stampaTabella(v);
table = new CustomTableArticoliDett(tableModel2);
table.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter2());
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

when I call tableModel2.stampaTabella(v) this method, call removeAllRow(); but I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.checkAgainstModel(DefaultRowSorter.java:921)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsDeleted(DefaultRowSorter.java:878)
    at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4274)
    at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4118)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4395)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(AbstractTableModel.java:261)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:464)
    at com.mcsolution.table.MioTableModel.defaultTableModel.removeAllRow(defaultTableModel.java:33)
    at com.mcsolution.easyMgmt.panel.articoli.articoliDettProfumeria.panelArticoliDett_GraficaProfumeria.daiProprieta(panelArticoliDett_GraficaProfumeria.java:432)
    at com.mcsolution.easyMgmt.panel.articoli.articoliDettProfumeria.panelArticoliDett_GraficaProfumeria.getPanelPrincipale(panelArticoliDett_GraficaProfumeria.java:105)
    at com.mcsolution.easyMgmt.panel.articoli.articoliDettProfumeria.PanelArticoliDett_QuintaStrada.creaSwing(PanelArticoliDett_QuintaStrada.java:67)
    at com.mcsolution.esp.TestaFrameQuintaStrada$MenuLookDemo22$18.actionPerformed(TestaFrameQuintaStrada.java:450)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Hi, use one of the solutions mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577792/how-to-clear-jtable

Comment: The solution not works, but I have know the problems. If I try to remove table.setRowSorter(sorter), my code works. Now how can fixed it?

Comment: Why don't you just use `table.setRowCount( 0 )` to remove all rows?