# Deleting all the rows in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to remove all the rows in my JTable.

I have tried both of the following:

```
/**
 * Removes all the rows in the table
 */
public void clearTable()
{
    DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) getModel();
    dm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
    revalidate();
}
```

and

```
((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).setNumRows(0);
```

Neither of which would remove all the rows. Any ideas?

Comment: @MByD I just added revalidate(), but still seeing the same thing. I am using a CustomeTableCellRenderer, but wouldnt think that would do too much.

Comment: I tried this as well. No luck. I think there is something else going on.

Comment: @MByD, no you shouldn't revalidate() or repaint(). The TableModel is responsible for notifying the JTable that something has changed so the table can repaint itself automatically.

Comment: @camickr - that for the information :)

Comment: voting to close as not-a-real-question - it's not answerable as posted, and evokes one incorrect pseudo-answer after another ...

Comment: check if [this][1] this solves your problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25020658/2553431

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) getModel();
int rowCount = dm.getRowCount();
//Remove rows one by one from the end of the table
for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    dm.removeRow(i);
}
```

Comment: -1, Actually, this code doesn't work. First you remove row 0, then all the rows shift down 1. Then you delete row 1, which means row 0 is still there. James_Bond's answer shows how this is done by deleting from the end not the start.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the array elements have to be removed from back to front.

Comment: no need for looping - DefaultTableModel _has_ api to clear all rows with a single method call ...

Comment: Wondering how this code can work with the `i++`. Should probably be `i--`

Comment: It doesn't work, it will only delete half of the table, and throw an exception after that. You could replace `i` inside the loop with `0`.

Comment: Check the updated version. The idea is to remove rows from the end of the table.

Comment: `((DefaultTableModel) jtMyTable.getModel()).setRowCount(0)`

Answer (score 92):

We can use DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(int) for this purpose, refering to Java's Documentation:

> public void [setRowCount(int rowCount)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setRowCount(int))
>
> Sets the number of rows in the model. If the new size is greater than
>   the current size, new rows are added to the end of the model If the
>   new size is less than the current size, **all rows at index rowCount
>   and greater are discarded**.

This means, we can clear a table like this:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jtMyTable.getModel();
dtm.setRowCount(0);
```

Now, on "how does java discard those rows?", I believe it just calls some C-like free(void*) ultimately somewhen, or maybe it just removes all references to that memory zone and leaves it for GC to care about, the documentation isn't quite clear regarding how this function works internally.

Comment: Great and simple code. Although the flagged answer to this question is also correct, it has problem when it comes on deleting thousands of rows. If you're handling thousands of row, this code is a snap.

Comment: This one clear all table rows. Easy and usable. Thanks

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Best answer for mee too, and with this is not necessary to iter in all table rows. Quite a strange method I would say.

Answer (score 22):

Something like this should work

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)this.getModel(); 
int rows = model.getRowCount(); 
for(int i = rows - 1; i >=0; i--)
{
   model.removeRow(i); 
}
```

Comment: Assuming a typical array-like backing, this is far better than removing the elements front to back.

Comment: btw: it should be DefaultTableModel, TableModel has no method removeRow

Comment: no need for looping, simply use the api that is meant for clearing the data (not too obvious, but then you probably read @camickr 's answer - which mentions the deprecated method)

Answer (score 14):

Read the API for DefaultTableModel - setRowCount method supports deleting/discarding all rows in one go...

`((DefaultTableModel)myTable.getModel()).setRowCount(0);`

Comment: correct, but nothing new: there is already [an earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15636607/203657) pointing to that exact method :-) Plus more than one pointing to the older api ..

Answer (score 9):

Well, setNumRows(0) should work, although if you actually read the API it tells you that this method is obsolete and tell you which method to use instead.

If the code doesn't work, then you are doing something else wrong and we can't tell from the posted code what that might be.

Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to remove all rows from JTable, just use this method instead...

```
tablemodel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
tablemodel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

`tablemodel` is the model which you created for your table to add new rows. This is the shortest and fastest way of deleting all rows because what if you have thousands of rows? Looping?

Comment: might appear simple - but is _wrong_: a) the general rule is to never-ever call any fireXX from outside of the model, notifying its listeners is the exclusive responsibility of the model itself. b) DefaultTableModel _has_ api to clear remove all rows (though its name is unfortunate), there's absolutely no need to interact with the underlying data structure

Comment: @kleopatra could you please explain the rule you are talking about? i dont understand why i can't use any fireXX method when they are public and accessible by default implementation!

Comment: it's a design accident that they are public - plain OO sanity requires that a) the class does its job completely and b) outsiders never-ever take over the job someone else is responsible for

Answer (score 6):

```
try{

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();

    dtm.setNumRows(0); 

}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have lots of rows but very few columns...

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
for(int i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++) dtm.addColumn(COLUMN_NAME[i]);
myTable.setModel(dtm);
```

...replaces the old DTM with a fresh one.

Comment: while possible, would not recommended (especially, as it's not needed, the DTM _has_ api to remove all its rows) - the implication is that listeners to the old model must be re-wired to the new model. Not rocket science, though, just unnecessary complexity ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, just use

`tableModel.setRowCount(0);` or  `tableModel.setNumRows(0);`

> Sets the number of rows in the model. If the new size is greater than
> the current size, new rows are added to the end of the model If the
> new size is less than the current size, all rows at index rowCount and
> greater are discarded. Params: rowCount – number of rows in the model

By setting the number of rows to zero you're are telling the table moble to have no rows, which makes the  table empty.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. This will remove all the rows from JTable.

```
DefaultTableModel model=new DefaulTableModel(rows,cols);
JTable table=new JTable(model);
for(int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i=i+0)
{
 model.removeRow(0);
 revalidate();
 }
```

Comment: -1 sigh - yet another variant of an incorrect answer ... **NO** there is no need at all to loop and **NO** there is even less a need to revalidate anything in that loop

Answer (score -1):

```
DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) tbl.getModel();
while(tbl.getRowCount() > 0)
{
    ((DefaultTableModel) tbl.getModel()).removeRow(0);
}
```

Comment: While this code may help answer the question, code only answers are not high quality. A better answer would explain what the code does, tell where to insert it, explain why this approach was taken, and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I had multiple tables, so I created a method to clear "any" table:

```java
private void deleteAllTableRows(JTable table) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    while( model.getRowCount() > 0 ){
        model.removeRow(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MyModel myTableModel = (MyModel) myTable.getModel();
for (int i = myTableModel.getRowCount()-1; i >= 0; i--) myTableModel.deleteRow(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not simple use for loops here because in every loop you remove a row which decreases the row count. Here's the right one:

```
int count = tmodel.getRowCount();
    while(count > 0) {
        tmodel.removeRow(count-1);
        count = tmodel.getRowCount();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    DefaultTableModel tb = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    if (jTable1.getSelectedRow() == 0) {
    } else {
        jTable1.selectAll();
        int t = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        while (t >= 0) {
            tb.removeRow(t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)